# jquery select all elements containing other element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got the following html (simplified)

```
<nav>
 <ul>

  <li>
  </li>

  <li>
   <ul>
   </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
   <ul>
   </ul>
  </li>

 </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I want to select all <li> that contain a <ul> and edit them. Change bg-color for example.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mplungjan - already two votes for a broken link - respect! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) or [:has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)

```
$('li').has('ul').dosomething();
$('li:has(ul)').dosomething();
```

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
$('li:has(ul)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

`:has()` or `.has()` lets you filter your selector down to elements that contain the specified elements.